# Vuejs: I need to reset the button back to the first name after pressing the button the third time

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this vuejs code and I am trying to do loop effect with a button. I would like the button to go back to the first comment (that is in the Javascript) straight after clicking on the button for the third time. Below is my HTML and Javascript code. Many thanks is advance.

HTML:

```
<button class="next" @click="increment"> > </button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
    testimonialData: [
      {
        name: 'W',
        comments: 'It was great.',
        stars: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'Tom',
        comments: 'Easy to use.',
        stars: 4
      },
      {
        name: 'Has',
        comments: 'Test',
        stars: 3
      }
    ],
    number: 0
  }
  },
  methods:{
    increment: function(){
      this.number ++;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/aGPrVX?editors=1010

Comment: Many thanks for this code. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return{
    testimonialData: [
      {
        name: 'W',
        comments: 'It was great.',
        stars: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'Tom',
        comments: 'Easy to use.',
        stars: 4
      },
      {
        name: 'Has',
        comments: 'Test',
        stars: 3
      }
    ],
    counter: 0
  }
  },
  methods:{
  increment(){
   if((this.testimonialData.length - 1) === this.counter) {
    this.counter = 0;
   }
   else {
    this.counter++;
   }
  }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>{{testimonialData[counter].comments}}</h3>
  <hr>
  <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      testimonialData: [{
          name: 'W',
          comments: 'It was great.',
          stars: 5
        },
        {
          name: 'Tom',
          comments: 'Easy to use.',
          stars: 4
        },
        {
          name: 'Has',
          comments: 'Test',
          stars: 3
        }
      ],
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      //for generic if(this.counter === this.testimonialData.length - 1)
      if (this.counter == 2)
        this.counter = 0;
      else
        this.counter++;

    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="next" @click="increment"> > </button>
  <h3>{{testimonialData[counter].name}}</h3>
  <h4>"{{testimonialData[counter].comments}}" with
    <span>{{testimonialData[counter].stars}} star/s.</span>
  </h4>
</div>
```